# How to change CQL version?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

When i try to connect to cqlsh I get this error:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': ProtocolError("cql_version '3.3.1' is not supported by remote (w/ native protocol). Supported versions: [u'3.4.4']",)})
```

If I add explicitly version like this `cqlsh --cqlversion=3.4.4` it is fine, but I wonder how to set CQL version to be 3.4.4 by default so I can connect without parameter ?

Answer (score 25):

You can specify this in your .cassandra/cqlshrc file:

```
[cql]
version=3.4.4
```